# Mongodb in Nodejs find method calls once

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

Hi I'm stuck with this little problem since yesterday. 
So in here I'm just trying to get the url from Mongodb that matches my parameter url and then redirect to the returned original_url.
It seems to work once but when I call it again. I gives me an error. 
I tried many different methods from Mongodb and still can't get it working.
Here are the calls:

```
const func = (short_url, cb) => {
  db.collection('urls')
    .find({short_url: short_url})
    .each((err, doc) => {
      if(err) console.log(err);
      if(doc) {
        cb(doc.original_url)
      } else {
        console.log('You came back');
      }
      db.close();  
    });
};

app.get('/:url', (req, res) => {
  const currentUrl = `https://${req.headers.host}/${req.params.url}`;
  const cb = (url) => { 
    res.redirect(url);
  };
  func(currentUrl, cb);
});
```

When it first fires, It gets the returned value but at the same time it goes back to the func function and returns the **'You came back'** console.log too.

The next time I call the same url, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

I have no idea on how to get it sorted. I'm exhausted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the currentUrl value next time you visit

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I just did and it's the same.